# Default page in Spring MVC does not render if I add Spring tag

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to create a simple web application which uses Spring MVC. Here I used Spring tag to link the resources folder. I like to add CSS(div{color:red}) to the default page(index.jsp) as well but it does not render when I add the Spring tag. The welcome.jsp is working properly when I add it there. What could be blocking the jsp file from not rendering properly? I attached the screenshots related to this question. I also included the code involved in **web.xml**, **pom.xml**,**servlet.xml** and the **controller** class for reference.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
    <display-name>CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Bean Configuration File**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.crunchify.controller" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/"
        mapping="/resources/**" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```java
package com.crunchify.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/*
 * author: Crunchify.com
 * 
 */

@Controller
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```html
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<spring:url value="resources/style.css" var="style" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${style}" />
<title>Spring MVC Tutorial Series by Crunchify.com</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url('https://cdn.crunchify.com/bg.png');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h2>
            Hey You..!! This is your 1st Spring MCV Tutorial..<br> <br>
        </h2>
        <h3>
            <a href="welcome.html">Click here to See Welcome Message... </a>(to
            check Spring MVC Controller... @RequestMapping("/welcome"))
        </h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error Screenshot**
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haJtN.png)

**Project Structure**
[Structure of Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLh2x.png)

Comment: Please read [why you should not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Hi @Chaosfire, I have formatted the other codes and left two images for reference since my error looks like a normal jsp file. An image would show better of the error I'm trying to explain. Thanks for pointing out :)